# Por que em OpenGL precisamos transformar todos os objetos para renderizá-los?

Tags: opengl

Sou iniciante em OpengGL e estou tendo algumas dificuldades para assimilar alguns conceitos. Estou lendo o livro [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics 3ª Ed.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1435458869), na parte em que o autor explica os diversos sistemas de coordenadas que o OpenGL usa para descrever os objetos.

Pelo que entendi há 5 sistemas de coordenadas, sendo eles:

1. **Object Space**: responsável por determinar as coordenadas dos vértices de um objeto relativas a este mesmo objeto. Cada objeto possui seu próprio object space.
2. **World Space**: responsável por determinar as coordenadas de todos vértices de todos os objetos em respeito às coordenada do "mundo 3d". Há um **único** World Space.
3. **Camera Space**: pelo que entendi o OpenGL só é capaz de renderizar objetos do **World Space** que estejam dento de um cubo **fixo** limitado no intervalo [-1, 1] nos eixos **x**, **y** e **z**. Este cubo também está no **World Space**. Portanto, para que nossos objetos possam ser renderizados, precisamos transformá-los de modo que eles "entrem" dentro do cubo.
4. **Homogeneus Clip Space**: depois que transformamos nossos objetos para a **Camera Space**, precisamos projetá-los em um plano (não sei qual) e ignorar os objetos cujas coordenadas projetadas saiam do intervalo [-1, 1]. Denominamos esse espaço de projeção como **Homogeneus Clip Space**. Também não consegui entender esse homogeneus. É nessa etapa que as coordenadas **z** dos vértices vão para o **Z-Buffer**?
5. **Window Space**: depois que projetamos nossos objetos para o **Homogeneus Clip Space**, todos os vértices restantes estão no intervalo [-1, 1] e precisam ser mapeados para a tela da máquina, em especial para a **Viewport** definida anteriormente.

As transformações de espaço para espaço são feitas através de **matrizes**. A matriz que transforma o **Object Space** no **World Space** se chama **Model Matrix**. A matriz que transforma o **World Space** na **Camera Space** se chama **View Matrix**. Podemos criar uma única matriz que leva o **Object Space** para a **Camera Space** multiplicando a **Model Matrix** pela **View Matrix**. Denominamos essa última como **Model-View Matrix** e a transformação dada por ela como **Model-View Transformation**.

[image: Imagem descrevendo as transformações entre os sistemas de coordenadas. Imagem 1.3, retirada do livro citado]

Escrevi tudo que consegui entender para que vocês possam me corrigir em algo que falei de errado, ou reforcem algum conceito.

A minha pergunta principal é: por que a OpenGL ao invés de fazer todas essas transformações nos objetos, ela apenas nos possibilitasse posicionar o nosso objeto no **World Space** e definir uma câmera nesse mesmo espaço e apenas ela seja transformada? Não é uma perda de desempenho fazer esse tanto de transformações nos objetos a todo frame?

Enfim, essa foi minha dúvida. Peço encarecidamente que me corrijam se falei algo errado.

Answer (score 1):

Em clip space as coordenadas têm de ser entre -1 e 1 mas nós definimos um range tipo 0 a 100 e o OpenGL converte automaticamente para clip space. O Z-Buffer é gerado em window space.

Object space são as coordenadas do objeto em relação à sua origem. Se quisermos posicionar este objeto em world space aplicamos uma translação no objeto.

A Projection matrix aplica a perspetiva nas coordenadas 3D e converte para clip space. Aqui definimos também o rácio da tela e a abertura da lente.

A posição do objeto pode ser diferente em cada frame. Podemos efetuar transformações não só na câmara mas também nos objetos. Na verdade a câmara está sempre no mesmo sítio e o mundo gira à volta dela. A vantagem do OpenGL é que podemos definir estes parâmetros para qualquer perspetiva e tirar partido do GPU.